# Deep Learning: Out of Memory error for data that's too wide

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm trying to build a model (using tensorflow) that makes use of LSTMs. My training examples aren't too big - I have only about 500 examples. But each of those examples is a vector of  size 2500. I keep getting Out of Memory errors every time I attempt to train the model. I tried using batching with small batch sizes (of 32 and 64) to reduce the size of the data, but the OOM error still persists.

What does one do when the training data is too wide?

Thank you very much!

Comment: this is a nasty issue indeed. Have a look at this https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/1817

Comment: @deadcode Thak you very much! This helps a lot!